# Deprecated feature 'DROP INDEX with two-part name' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Query to delete Indexer from table in SQL Azure

```
  Drop index [dbo].[Visulaization_UnitUserMapping].IX_Visulaization_UnitUserMapping_UnitUserId;
```

but I am getting error : Deprecated feature 'DROP INDEX with two-part name' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Is there any other way to get this done in SQL Azure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You drop an index using the following syntax:

```
DROP INDEX IX_Visulaization_UnitUserMapping_UnitUserId 
   ON [dbo].[Visulaization_UnitUserMapping]
```

i.e.

```
DROP INDEX IndexName
   ON SchemaName.TableName
```

Ref.: [DROP INDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx)